Component is not re-rendering although the state is changing
import { Row,Col,Navbar,Button,Form,Card,Image,Table,Container, Stack} from "react-bootstrap";
import {Link, useNavigate,useParams} from "react-router-dom"
import {React, useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './GameComponents.css' 
import API from "../API.mjs";

//ignore this component
function Timer(){
    const [seconds,setSeconds]= useState(30);
    const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(100);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (seconds > 0) {
          const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            setSeconds(seconds - 1);
            setPercentage((seconds - 1) / 30 * 100); // Calculate percentage
            }, 1000);
          return () => clearTimeout(timerId); // clean timeout
        }
      }, [seconds]);
    return(    
    <Card> 
        <Card.Body> 
        <div>
      <h1 className="TimerTitle">Timer: {seconds} seconds</h1>
      <div className="progress-bar">
        <div
          className="progress-bar-fill"
          style={{ width: `${percentage}%` }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>

        </Card.Body> 
    </Card> 
    );
}
//ignore this component 
function ImageContainer(props){

    //console.log(props.memes);
    return(
    <Image className="image-container image-border" src='./src/images/tradeoffer.jpg' rounded/>
);

}
//console.log is not printed the first time, then it is printed
function AnswersContainer(props){
    console.log(props.captions)
return(<>
 <Stack gap={5} className="CaptionComponent">
    {props.captions.map((caption)=>{
        <Row><Answer caption={caption}/></Row>
    })}
    </Stack>
</>)

}
//this console.log() is never printed
function Answer(props){
    console.log("inside answer")
    return(
        <Row>
            <Button variant="light">{props.caption}</Button>
        </Row>
    );
    
}
function GameComponent(){
    const [memes,setMemes]= useState([]);
    const [captions,setCaptions]= useState([]);

    //useEffect to set memes state
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getMeme=async ()=>{
            const m=await API.getMemes();
            setMemes(m);
        }
        getMeme();
    },[]);  

    //useEffect to set captions state
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getCaption=async ()=>{
            const c=await API.getCaptions();
            setCaptions(c);
        }
        getCaption();
    },[]);  

    return(<>
    <Container className="MainContainer">
        <Card>
            <Row>
                <Timer/>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}> 
                    <ImageContainer memes={memes}/>
                </Col>
                <Col md={6}>
                    <AnswersContainer captions={captions}/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Card>
    </Container> 
    </>);
}

export default GameComponent;

Hi everybody I'm writing because I have a problem, in the function GameComponent() I use an useEffect to change the state of captions, which I then use in the AnswerContainer and Answer components to show the possible answer (the app I'm trying to make has a table with a meme on the left column and 7 possible captions/answers which I get from the server through the API call).
The problem is that I'm not seeing anything in the Answer components, not even the console.log(), while in the AnswerContainer component I see the console.log of props.caption. The first are empty, then I see the console.log() actually print the captions I wrote in the DB, so this reassures me the API call works, the state is updated but no component re-rendering.

<Row><Answer caption={caption}/></Row> You need a return in front of this

Nicholas has the answer, you did not return any element in the map. add the return statement, or remove the durly brackets if you intended to write in shorthand

wait do you mean something like this?
function AnswersContainer(props){
console.log(props.captions)
return(<>

{props.captions.map((caption)=>{
return 
})}

</>)

Mapping with curly brackets in a function does not return anything by default.
There are two ways to fix this code:

either you remove the curly brackets:
return (
<>
  <Stack gap={5} className="CaptionComponent">
    {props.captions.map((caption) => (
      <Row>
        <Answer caption={caption} />
      </Row>
    ))}
  </Stack>
</> 
);


or add a return statement:
return (
<>
  <Stack gap={5} className="CaptionComponent">
    {props.captions.map((caption) => {
      return (
        <Row>
          <Answer caption={caption} />
        </Row>
      );
    })}
  </Stack>
</>
);




Just FYI there's a VTC (Vote To Close) reason specific to "Not Reproducible or was cause by typo" type issues and we typically close issues like this as such because they only help the OP now and are not considered of any longterm value to future readers.
